# problem appending an array and printing it in Python

Tags: python

I cant make append work. When i try to add passengers and then print my array it just empy []

```
class Buss:

  passengers=np.array([])

  number_of_passengers=0

#menu option 0
def add_passenger(passengers):
  replit.clear()
  age = int(input("Ange ålder på passageraren här: "))
  print(age)
  passengers:np.append(age)
  if len(passengers)>25:
    print("Nu är tyvärr bussen full")
  input("Tryck Enter för att gå tillbaka till menyvalen")
   

#menu option 1
def print_bus(passengers):
  replit.clear()
  print("Alla passagerare på bussen: ")
  print(passengers)
  input("Tryck Enter för att gå tillbaka till menyvalen")
```

Comment: Is there a requirement, or other good reason, to use numpy for this assignment?

Comment: its a requirment and i never used numpy before. I have tried with = aswell but then the np gets a red line under

Comment: `passengers = np.append(passengers, age)` would make sense perhaps.

Comment: i tried passengers=np.append(passengers,age) but i still get an empty array when i print :(

Answer (score 1):

I can see some syntax errors here and there. Also you need to use list to append an element to it instead of a numpy array. The modified code is shown below.

```
passengers = []

#menu option 0
def add_passenger(passengers):
  replit.clear()
  age = int(input("Ange ålder på passageraren här: "))
  print(age)
  passengers.append(age)
  if len(passengers)>25:
    print("Nu är tyvärr bussen full")
  input("Tryck Enter för att gå tillbaka till menyvalen")
   

#menu option 1
def print_bus(passengers):
  replit.clear()
  print("Alla passagerare på bussen: ")
  print(passengers)
  input("Tryck Enter för att gå tillbaka till menyvalen")
```

This should solve the problem. I have removed the class and made the passengers list a global variable accessible to both the functions.

Comment: I have to have the class as a part of my project so what do I do then? and I also need to have it as a numpy array to pass

Answer (score 0):

I believe (I haven't tested it, just from reading the code) you got an error in this line:

```
passengers:np.append(age)
```

It should be `passengers = np.append(age)` because you're assigning to passengers the result of the append operation (equal in place of colon).

As a bonus, given you say you're starting to code, here it is something is gonna help you along the way: **learn how to debug**.

That's something is gonna help you with these cases (they appear even in senior code, so you're never gonna be free from them, they're part of the job).

As soon as you learn how to debug the code, you are gonna be able to understand it and correct it line by line, instead of as a whole.
Good luck.

Comment: How to read a traceback is a very big part of it. Here is the important msg: "TypeError: append() missing 1 required positional argument: 'values'".
Means that the append function needs a mandatory 'values' param that you're missing. Or, if 'values' is 'age', you're missing another positional value that goes first, it's taking age in its place and marking value as missing. (VERY common error, been there)
Go to numpy and check the docs for append, that's gonna give you more light about how that function works.
Go to the docs :)